# Link Module Title in Joomla 3

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0, joomla3.1

Would anyone be kind enough to point me to the right direction?

i'm using yootheme template and "gavick news show pro gk5" and can't figure out how to link to the module title!

I have tried gavick's own plugin but it works only in their templates. Not yootheme's. I tried with rokcandy too but nothing shows up. their support for free products are non-existent.

any thought would be great. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [link to Gavick](https://www.gavick.com/documentation/joomla-templates/templates-for-joomla-1-6/how-to-change-module-title-links/) - So if you want to change the link URL – go to the module settings and at the bottom of list you will find tab named “Module Title Links (GavickPro)” there you may make the required changes.

Answer (score 0):

I've found another good solution using "sourcerer" extension, you could see an example here:
https://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=690796

After loading the plugin just use the tags as in example to set a link to the module title

```
{source}[[a href="http://www.google.com"]]MODULE TITLE NAME[[/a]]{/source}
```